# WSUS on WinSrv2012 cannot serve Anniversary update Win10 v.1607

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus, windows-update

All my clients are stuck in downloading v1607 update for Windows 10 from my local WSUS server. When they tried to download it, an error 31 occurred (WindowsUpdate Cannot download the update).

I'm sure that my Wsus server has the KB3159706 installed and I also did the manual post-install steps:

- Command: `"C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools\wsusutil.exe" postinstall /servicing`
- Feature installation of HTTP Activation under .NET Framework 4.5 Features

This server has not SSL enabled, therefore I think there are not more required steps.

What is blocking the download?

Answer (score 0):

Here I found the solution:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d7dbb851-4e3a-41d9-9072-1f16d7b1bc1e/fix-domain-windows-10-wsus-upgrade-issues-file-not-found?forum=winserverwsus

I had to add a new mime-type entry in IIS service.